# Использование pug в однофайловых компонентах vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, pug

Хочу использовать pug в однофайловых компонентах vue.
Я понял, что шаблоны открывать нужно так:

```
<template lang="pug">
```

Но из документации так и не понял, нужно ли как-то конфигурировать vue-loader и pug-loader между собой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не нужно. `npm i -D pug` и все.

Из [официальной документации](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/ru/configurations/pre-processors.html):

> Обработка шаблонов выполняется несколько иначе, потому что большинство loader'ов шаблонов webpack, например pug-loader, возвращают функцию шаблона вместо скомпилированного в строку HTML. Поэтому вместо использования pug-loader, можно просто установить оригинальный pug.